# Regular expression with two non-repeating symbols in any order

Tags: python, regex

I need to create the regex that will match such string:

```
AA+1.01*2.01,BB*2.01+1.01,CC
```

Order of * and + should be any
I've created the following regex:

```
^(([A-Z][A-Z](([*+][0-9]+(\.[0-9])?[0-9]?){0,2}),)*[A-Z]{2}([*+][0-9]+(\.[0-9])?[0-9]?){0,2})$
```

But the problem is that with this regex + or * could be used twice but I only need any of them once so the following strings matches should be:

```
AA+1*2,CC - true
AA+1+2,CC - false (now is true with my regex)
AA*1+2,CC - true
AA*1*2,CC - false (now is true with my regex)
```

Comment: Please provide a better example of inputs and the desired output. What you have said doesn't really make any sense.

Comment: `(?=.*\+)(?=.*\*)`

Comment: Can the string be split on the commas? If there a limit to the number of commas?

Comment: @JaredGoguen no it cannot, no there is no limit

Comment: Try [`^[A-Z]{2}(?:([+*])(?:\d+(?:\.\d+)?)?(?!\1)[+*](?:\d+(?:\.\d+)?)?)?(?:,[A-Z]{2}(?:([+*])(?:\d+(?:\.\d+)?)?(?!\2)[+*](?:\d+(?:\.\d+)?)?)?)*$`](https://regex101.com/r/kU6nM7/1). Without more concrete specifications, it is difficult to help you properly.

Answer (score 0):

Either of the `[+*]` should be captured first and then use `negative lookahead` to match the other one.

**Regex:** `[A-Z]{2}([+*])(?:\d+(?:\.\d+)?)(?!\1)[+*](?:\d+(?:\.\d+)?),[A-Z]{2}`

**Explanation:**

- `[A-Z]{2}` Matches two upper case letters.
- `([+*])` captures either of `+` or `*`.
- `(?:\d+(?:\.\d+)?)` matches number with optional decimal part.
- `(?!\1)[+*]` looks ahead for symbol captured and matched the other one. So if `+` is captured previously then `*` will be matched.
- `(?:\d+(?:\.\d+)?)` matches number with optional decimal part.
- `,[A-Z]{2}` matches  `,` followed by two upper case letters.

**[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/qB5wT1/3)**

---

To match the first case `AA+1.01*2.01,BB*2.01+1.01,CC` which is just a little advancement over previous pattern, use following regex.

**Regex:** `(?:[A-Z]{2}([+*])(?:\d+(?:\.\d+)?)(?!\1)[+*](?:\d+(?:\.\d+)?),)+[A-Z]{2}`

**Explanation:** Added whole pattern except `,CC` in first group and made it greedy by using `+` to match one or more such patterns.

**[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/qB5wT1/8)**

Comment: The first example won't match then, see [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/qB5wT1/5)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: I think OP made a typo there. Check his later examples.

Comment: I do not know if there is a typo. Yes, let's wait. I have a regex matching all three correctly, but the question belongs to those I usually refrain from answering.

Comment: I don't follow _but the question belongs to those I usually refrain from answering._

Comment: You do not have to, I am weird.

Comment: "the question is a member of the set of questions which I usually refrain from answering"

Comment: @noob can you help me with matching the first example `AA+1.01*2.01,BB*2.01+1.01,CC` please, it doesn't work for now

Comment: @noob it strange but it is written here: http://pythex.org/ that this expression is invalid

Comment: @Roberto: [No it's not invalid. I checked it on pythex.org. Works fine](http://pythex.org/?regex=(%3F%3A%5BA-Z%5D%7B2%7D(%5B%2B*%5D)(%3F%3A%5Cd%2B(%3F%3A%5C.%5Cd%2B)%3F)(%3F!%5C1)%5B%2B*%5D(%3F%3A%5Cd%2B(%3F%3A%5C.%5Cd%2B)%3F)%2C)%2B%5BA-Z%5D%7B2%7D&test_string=AA%2B1*2%2CCC%0AAA%2B1%2B2%2CCC%0AAA*1%2B2%2CCC%0AAA*1*2%2CCC%0AAA%2B1.01*2.01%2CBB*2.01%2B1.01%2CCC&ignorecase=0&multiline=0&dotall=0&verbose=0)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: To match the first case. Check the last three comments.

Comment: The number of my previous comment upvotes is discouraging :(

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: It's a **Thug Life**. Deal with it :D

Answer (score 0):

To get a regex to match your given example, extended to an arbitrary number of commas, you could use:

```
^(?:[A-Z]{2}([+*])?\d*\.?\d*(?!\1)[+*]?\d*\.?\d*,?)*$
```

Note that this example will also allow a trailing comma. I'm not sure if there is much you can do about that.

[**Regex 101 Example**](https://regex101.com/r/qB5wT1/9)

If the trailing comma is an issue:

```
^(?:[A-Z]{2}([+*])?\d*\.?\d*(?!\1)[+*]?\d*\.?\d*,?)*?(?:[A-Z]{2}([+*])?\d*\.?\d*(?!\2)[+*]?\d*\.?\d*?)$
```

[**Regex 101 Example**](https://regex101.com/r/qB5wT1/10)

Comment: This will let a string end with a dangling comma.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew That was noted, but I've added a version to disallow that. I'd assume in most cases a dangling comma would be fine (but who knows).